# from keras.engine import InputSpec stopped working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I was using InputSpec in my code from 'keras.engine' but it has suddenly stopped importing in Google colab. Used to work fine till yesterday.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'InputSpec' from 'keras.engine' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/__init__.py)
```

I realise there is 'from keras.layers import InputSpec' which works without error. However, I was traing my model using InputSpec from 'keras.engine' and now I am unable to load previously saved model. When I try to load previously saved model I get the error

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 29 layers into a model with 24 layers.
```

Is there anyway I can use my older saved models again?

I was using InputSpec in Reflection Padding code

```
def spatial_reflection_2d_padding(x, padding=((1, 1), (1, 1)), data_format=None):

assert len(padding) == 2
assert len(padding[0]) == 2
assert len(padding[1]) == 2

if data_format is None:
    data_format = image_data_format()

if data_format not in {'channels_first', 'channels_last'}:
    raise ValueError('Unknown data_format ' + str(data_format))

if data_format == 'channels_first':
    pattern = [[0, 0],
               [0, 0],
               list(padding[0]),
               list(padding[1])]
else:
    pattern = [[0, 0],
               list(padding[0]), list(padding[1]),
               [0, 0]]
return tf.pad(x, pattern, "REFLECT")

class ReflectionPadding2D(Layer):

    def __init__(self,
                 padding=(1, 1),
                 data_format=None,
                 **kwargs):
        super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_format = normalize_data_format(data_format)
        if isinstance(padding, int):
            self.padding = ((padding, padding), (padding, padding))
        elif hasattr(padding, '__len__'):
            if len(padding) != 2:
                raise ValueError('`padding` should have two elements. '
                                 'Found: ' + str(padding))
            height_padding = conv_utils.normalize_tuple(padding[0], 2,
                                                        '1st entry of padding')
            width_padding = conv_utils.normalize_tuple(padding[1], 2,
                                                       '2nd entry of padding')
            self.padding = (height_padding, width_padding)
        else:
            raise ValueError('`padding` should be either an int, '
                             'a tuple of 2 ints '
                             '(symmetric_height_pad, symmetric_width_pad), '
                             'or a tuple of 2 tuples of 2 ints '
                             '((top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad)). '
                             'Found: ' + str(padding))
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=4)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if self.data_format == 'channels_first':
            if input_shape[2] is not None:
                rows = input_shape[2] + self.padding[0][0] + self.padding[0][1]
            else:
                rows = None
            if input_shape[3] is not None:
                cols = input_shape[3] + self.padding[1][0] + self.padding[1][1]
            else:
                cols = None
            return (input_shape[0],
                    input_shape[1],
                    rows,
                    cols)
        elif self.data_format == 'channels_last':
            if input_shape[1] is not None:
                rows = input_shape[1] + self.padding[0][0] + self.padding[0][1]
            else:
                rows = None
            if input_shape[2] is not None:
                cols = input_shape[2] + self.padding[1][0] + self.padding[1][1]
            else:
                cols = None
            return (input_shape[0],
                    rows,
                    cols,
                    input_shape[3])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return spatial_reflection_2d_padding(inputs,
                                             padding=self.padding,
                                             data_format=self.data_format)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'padding': self.padding,
                  'data_format': self.data_format}
        base_config = super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Code of generator model with mismatched layers

```
def generator_model():
inputs = Input(shape=image_shape)

x = ReflectionPadding2D((3, 3))(inputs)
x = Conv2D(filters=ngf, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='valid')(x)
x = InstanceNormalization()(x)
x0 = Activation('relu')(x)

n_downsampling = 2

mult = 1 #128 filters
x = Conv2D(filters=ngf*mult*2, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='same')(x0) 
x = InstanceNormalization()(x)
x1 = Activation('relu')(x)

mult = 2 #256 filters
x = Conv2D(filters=ngf*mult*2, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='same')(x1) 
x = InstanceNormalization()(x)
x2 = Activation('relu')(x)

mult = 2**n_downsampling
for i in range(n_blocks_gen):
    x = res_block(x, ngf*mult, use_dropout=True)   
x = concatenate([x, x2])

mult = 2**(n_downsampling - 0)
x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=int(ngf * mult / 2), kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = InstanceNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = concatenate([x, x1])

mult = 2**(n_downsampling - 1)
x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=int(ngf * mult / 2), kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x = InstanceNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = concatenate([x, x0])


x = ReflectionPadding2D((3, 3))(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=output_nc, kernel_size=(7, 7), padding='valid')(x)
x = Activation('tanh')(x)

outputs = Add()([x, inputs])
outputs = Lambda(lambda z: z/2)(outputs)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='Generator')
return model
```

Comment: Issue is because of latest Keras version release. Instead of `Keras.engine` use `from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputSpec`. Google colab has latest Tensorflow and Keras version that is 2.5. In which some of the Keras libraries are updated. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to fix it by using tensorflow 1.5 but before the update I was using tensorflow 2.x and I don't remember the exact version. Later when I tried different combination of tf2 and keras but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Try** importing

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputSpec
```

**instead** of

```
from keras.layers import InputSpec
```